# How to run an exe file from a Vb program

Tags: vb.net, exe

I use this code in VB to run an .EXE file that requires an input file and results in creation of an output file.

```
 Process.Start("C:\glob.exe","C:\g.inp" )
```

It seems that the exe runs successfully but the output file **don't get created**.

**Note** when I run the exe file from cmd it makes the output files at the end so there's nothing wrong with the exe file.

Comment: That sounds like a very specific issue with your executable; it may be throwing an error that you're not catching.

Comment: Try running your exe as admin. Most likely the program does not have admin rights and so won't have permission to create a file in the root of the C drive

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` with `ProcessStartInfo` to specify various parameters to launch your executable.
The `Process` class gives you more control on the launched program than the `Shell` function.

e.g.

```
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
    psi.FileName = "C:\glob.exe"
    psi.Arguments = "C:\g.inp"
    psi.Verb = "runas"
    Process.Start(psi)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use shell function in vb.net
Shell("C:\procexp.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)